# Authorization Code Flow code examples for ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am trying to implement Single-sign on for my ASP.NET web application using Azure Active Directory and the OAuth2 OpenIDConnect protocols. The documentation is recommending that implicit grant flow is used only for SPA, however, all code samples for ASP.NET are using the response_Type of idTokens. Inorder for this response type to work I need to allow the implicit grant flow. Can anyone point me to code samples using MSAL that can work with the authorization code grant?

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `OAuth 2 authorization code grant` can be used in apps that are installed on a device to gain access to protected resources like web APIs. This allows you to add sign-in and API access to your mobile and desktop apps.

To redeem an authorization code and get a token, and cache it, the `IConfidentialClientApplication` contains a method called.

```
AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
            IEnumerable<string> scopes,
            string authorizationCode)
```

Here is code [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#desktop-and-mobile-public-client-apps) you could refer to and this [one](https://developermessaging.azurewebsites.net/2019/10/07/msal-basics-a-guide-to-azure-ads-authentication-library/).